# Why do Facebook notifications still make sounds even after I turn off "Play a sound when each new notification is received"?

Tags: facebook

So from https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications&section=on_facebook&view, I have both "Play a sound when each new notification is received" and "Play a sound when a message is received" both set to off, and for some reason I still get sounds on Firefox/Chrome from Facebook Messenger. How can I concretely turn these sounds off?

Comment: Try clearing Google Chrome/Firefox's browsing data and cookies, then close and re-open your browser.